# Unable to install and run Android Emulator for VSCode without Installing Android Studio

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, emulation

I'm new to VScode and Flutter development. I'm attempting to install and run an android emulator in VScode without installing Android studio. The following is the step my step process which I have followed.

1. Installed VSCode in "C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe".
2. Extracted Flutter SDK 3.0.0 in E:\ as E:\flutter.
3. Downloaded tools_r26.1.1-windows and extracted it to E:\Android SDK.
4. In VScode, Installed Dart and flutter plugins respectively.
5. Set SDK path using the following command in VScode terminal
   "flutter config --android-sdk E:\Android SDK".
   I get response as Setting "android-sdk" value to "E:\Android". I restart IDE and goto next step.
6. Updated the paths in Environment variables by adding E:\flutter\bin to Path in both System and User Variables. Did the same for the Android SDK folder.
7. Ran Flutter Doctor and I get the following response

```
    [√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.675], locale en-IN)
    [X] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
        X Unable to locate Android SDK.
          Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
          On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
          (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for detailed instructions).
          If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, please use
          `flutter config --android-sdk` to update to that location.

    [X] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at .\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe)
        ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.
    [X] Visual Studio - develop for Windows
        X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
          Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
          Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components
    [!] Android Studio (not installed)
    [√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.67.1)
    [√] Connected device (2 available)
    [√] HTTP Host Availability

    ! Doctor found issues in 4 categories.
```

8. When i attempt to start emulator using ctrl+shift+p and select Flutter:Launch Emulator i can the follwing error

```
    avdmanager is missing from the Android SDK
```

I need help here. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The "tools" are deprecated and outdated (e.g. have problems with Java 11). You should download and use the emulator package instead. Make sure your Android SDK path has the proper sub-directory structure like this: `E:\Android\tools\emulator.exe` for the tools package respectively `E:\Android\emulator\emulator.exe` for the emulator package.

Comment: @Robert where can I download the emulator package ?- in essence what's the correct technical term for the package?

Comment: Use the Android command-line tools (without without Android Studio): https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#command-tools It includes the command-line sdk-manager for downloading the necessary packages.

Comment: Getting this error while using cmd line tools "PS C:\cmdline-tools\bin> .\sdkmanager.bat --list
Error: Could not determine SDK root.
Error: Either specify it explicitly with --sdk_root= or move this package into its expected location: <sdk>\cmdline-tools\latest\
PS C:\cmdline-tools\bin>

Comment: I did the following - Renamed "cmdtools" to "tools" and placed it inside C:\Android\cmdline-tools\ as C:\Android\cmdline-tools\tools\ and it worked.

Comment: As I wrote the tools package is heavily outdated (not updated for years) you should not use it anymore. In the end you will only run into problems using it. Install the `emulator` package instead.

Comment: @Robert.The emulator installed to C:\Android\emulator. However I'm still getting the same error - "avdmanager is missing from the Android SDK"

Comment: @Robert - My emulator is installed in C:\Android\emulator. flutter android SDK path I have set to the above using command line. What steps should I take now ?

Comment: `avdmanager` is part of the command-line tools package which is installed by default if you finally would do what I suggest and install a full Android SDK.

Answer (score -1):

You look at the build tab at the bottom of the screen, it will display the error message and option to install the Build tools. Install it and you should be able to see the AVD Manager. Another way is to go to the SDK Manager. Under SDK Tools you will find the Android SDK Build tools.
Reference Got from https://www.tektutorialshub.com/android-studio/avd-manager-sdk-manager-missing-or-greyed-out-in-android-studio

Comment: The OP ask for Android SDK without Android Studio and your answer clearly points to have Android Studio installed.